# MariaDB "underlying table doesn't have a default value" on event creation

Tags: civievent, mysql, drupal-7, mariadb

I'm using CiviCRM 5.50.4 on Drupal 7 with MariaDB.
The NGO I volunteer for uses French language.
When a user creates an event, we have the following error (debugging mode):

```
UserInfo    INSERT INTO `civicrm_price_set_fr_FR` (`name` , `title` , `is_active` , `extends` , `financial_type_id` , `is_quick_config` , `is_reserved` , `min_amount` ) VALUES ('apprice_set_508' , 'AP [Copie id 508]' , 1 , '1' , 4 , 1 , 0 , 0.00 ) [nativecode=1423 ** Field of view 'drupal.civicrm_price_set_fr_FR' underlying table doesn't have a default value]
```

Thanks to PhpMyadmin, I discovered the `civicrm_price_set_fr_FR` is a view based on the table `civicrm_price_set` and two of the view fields don't have a default value.

**Question 1** - I identified two resolution possibilities:

1. I could set MariaDb to ignore that with the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES parameter - but it means not catching abnormal queries anymore
2. I could work to set a default value - but I still haven't figure out how to do so

Any advice?

**Question 2** - Despite this error message, the actual issue is that I can't register Contacts on new Events since I can't save mandatory pricing information: I don't know if the above issue is the root cause of that or equally a consequence of another issue ...

**Question 3** - Should I, someday, report this as a bug or an evolution request to avoid this issue to happen to other users?

Thanks for your help, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks Demerit for your answer.
Indeed, I disabled the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES option and the issue disapeared. Let's hope disabling this safety won't let actual problems happend ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem that mariadb isn't very usable with multilingual with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. There's a thought about how it could be solved at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22647#issuecomment-1026131715

Comment: I did not understand: if I am using MariaDB (my current version is 10.6.9), do I have to disable STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.
I have upgraded to CiviCRM latest version (5.52.2) and `civicrm_price_set` trigggers are 
`IF NEW.title_de_DE IS NOT NULL THEN SET NEW.title_it_IT = NEW.title_de_DE; ELSEIF ...`
shouldn't they be updated with your change?

Comment: Yes for now you have to disable STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. The trigger isn't really the problem it's that the schema has no default, which causes a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this related to [DB Error : Uknown error (When a new profile is created in multilingual CiviCRM setup)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42223/db-error-uknown-error-when-a-new-profile-is-created-in-multilingual-civicrm-s) ?

A solution could be to set the _fr_FR columns to NULL (if they are NOT NULL now)